# React Hook "useState" is called in function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have button click system and it works.

```
function clickCreate(msg){
    console.log(msg);
}
const CreateButton = (props) =>{
  return(
    <div>
    <i onClick = {() => clickCreate("test")} id="createBtn" className="fas fa-5x fa-microphone-alt"></i>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Now I want to fetch the API inside the function.

So, change the function `clickCreate` like this

```
function clickCreate(msg){
  const [result, setResult] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get('http://localhost:8000/api/genres/')
      .then((res)=> {
      console.log(res.data.items);
      setResult(res.data.items);
    }).catch(err=>{console.log(err);});
  }, []);
}
```

However there comes error like this.

I should not use useState and useEffect in function, but how can trigger the API by btn click??

```
./src/views/Components/Components.js
  Line 168:31:  React Hook "useState" is called in function "clickCreate" which is neither a React function component or a custom React Hook function   react-hooks/rules-of-hooks
  Line 170:3:   React Hook "useEffect" is called in function "clickCreate" which is neither a React function component or a custom React Hook function  react-hooks/rules-of-hooks

Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.
```

Comment: A useEffect and useState inside a callback makes no sense, what are you expecting it to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should move the hook to component level ([Rules of hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html#gatsby-focus-wrapper)), then you can fetch on click and use the hook's setter:

```
const CreateButton = (props) => {
  const [result, setResult] = useState([]);

  // should be in scope with `setResult`
  function clickCreate() {
    axios
      .get("http://localhost:8000/api/genres/")
      .then((res) => {
        console.log(res.data.items);
        setResult(res.data.items);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <i
        onClick={clickCreate}
        id="createBtn"
        className="fas fa-5x fa-microphone-alt"
      ></i>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I understood. I can omit `useEffect`

Answer (score 0):

I think a better approach would be to move the function in the component and take `useState` out.

```
const CreateButton = (props) =>{
  const [result, setResult] = useState([]);

  const clickCreate = async (msg) => {
      console.log(msg);
      let res = await axios.get('http://localhost:8000/api/genres/');
      setResult(res.data.items);
  }

  return(
    <div>
    <i onClick = {() => clickCreate("test")} id="createBtn" className="fas fa-5x fa-microphone-alt"></i>
    </div>
  );
}
```